# Are universities strongly associated with ethnic minority groups a thing outside the USA?

Tags: university, diversity, ethnicity, minority

[This](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/9438/why-is-howard-university-still-predominantly-black) question asks about the history of why Howard University in Washington, DC, USA has remained a school whose student and faculty bodies are predominantly African-American.

Do "historically [minority ethnic group]" universities exist *in a meaningful sense* outside the USA? For example, are there universities in Spain which are historically known for targeting or serving the ethnic Basque community? Are there "Historically Italian" universities in Argentina? Do the Ainu of Japan tend to predominate at a specific Japanese university?

This question is not about whether specialized minority-serving academic institutions *should* exist, or what their social, political, or economic ramifications are, if any.

This question involves something other than a request to churn and process statistical data - it is a question about social realities and social perceptions in academia. For example, if a census of a particular university in the UK happens to reveal that 65% of the faculty and students are Scottish Highlanders, but there is no significant social perception of the school as a "Highlander School" and no particular adherence to Highlander culture, then it would not count under this question. If, however, there is a UK university whose charter specifically says that it was established "for the education of Highlanders", or which inspires mentions of "oh, that Highlander school!" when mentioned casually in pubs, it counts, even if the actual number of Highlanders on campus as of 2018 is 15%.

Comment: Legal segregation of blacks from whites in the US is the reason for the existence of historically black universities/colleges. I suspect another category you would by more likely to find abroad are institutions that primarily or exclusively educate women.

Comment: Do you count countries with ethnic minorities that speak a different language?  Do Swedish-speaking universities in Finland, French or Italian speaking universities in Switzerland, or French-speaking universities in Belgium count?

Comment: As the situation in Spain has been mentioned, here universities aren't targeted to specific groups, although they use the languages of their area. Contrastingly with the USA, here most students don't travel far away. In addition there are private universities with religious backgrounds, but they aren't focused in students from their groups.

Comment: @BryanKrause South Africa has a similar history of segregation and has no historically black university as far as I can tell.

Comment: Are you asking about [minority servicing institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minority-serving_institution) in general or about historically X institutions. There are a number of new institutions with a goal of *servicing* minorities that would be hard to describe as historical.

Comment: @StrongBad I would describe recently-instituted minority-servicing institutions as in-scope. Even if these institutions do not have much in the way of history, they are clearly socially identified as being associated with minorities and thus their "history", even if short, has been one of being associated with minorities.

Comment: @AlexanderWoo if the language barrier has resulted in significant de-facto segregation by ethnic group or at least the perception of it, I would say it counts. If a country is mostly populated by bilinguals and citizens typically choose a university based on reasons other than the language spoken (e.g. prestige, program availability, climate, etc.), then it probably wouldn't count. For example, if large numbers of native Dutch-speaking fluent French-speaking Belgians attend French-language universities because they are easier to afford, those schools would probably not count.

Comment: @Pere Right. Also, for the particular example of the basque ethnic group, it would not be easy to establish the pertenence to such group. Maybe the concept itself of ethnicity is unclear outside the US. Language would be a clearer boundary e.g. in Belgium.

Comment: @RobertColumbia - I think all my examples count then.  Next question: do anglophones in Quebec count as a minority?  What about Flemish speakers in Brussels (or other French speaking parts of Belgium)?

Comment: @AlexanderWoo: Even though French might technically be a minority language in Belgium and French and Italian may technically be minority languages in Switzerland, nobody in those countries would call the respective groups "ethnic minorities". Internal social frictions notwithstanding, the respective groups are not "subordinate" to a majority population in any manner.

Comment: @user8001 Probably the central difference between the US and South Africa as far as this question goes is that half the US did *not* have state-mandated segregation. I'm no expert on this, but I believe that most of the earliest efforts to educate blacks in the US were initiatives by Northern abolitionists and religious groups like the Quakers.

Comment: I think @AlexanderWoo is right on the money. In most of the world, a different ethnic group will also speak a different language. If a university uses that language, it will "target" that ethnic group by default. As an example, take the [Sámi University of Applied Sciences](http://www.samas.no/en) in Norway. The university uses the Sami language, and so virtually all of its students will be Sami.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning - Um, what about Booker T. Washington?

Comment: @aparente001 Booker T. Washington is an excellent example of someone who was educated at a school founded by Northern abolitionists.

Comment: @ElizabethHenning - And after that?  Was what made Booker T. Washington so famous and influential the fact that he studied and cleaned his heart out as a student at Hampton?

Answer (score 7):

As universities in England were originally based on training religious folk for the priesthood, they did not accept other religions or non-religious persons, so alternative learning places evolved, which are now full universities, but the female/male divide was strong in learning establishments until recently. Imperial College, London was specifically created to allow Empire students of a non-UK-religious background get a university education in UK. They might be non-Christian, Non-Believers or even 'pagans' or even "Scots Protestants" but Imperial College was open to them while the older English religious founded establishments were not.

Comment: I was a student at Imperial in the late 1960's. By then, any remnant of the religious difference or special association with the former empire had gone.

Answer (score 4):

Trinity College Dublin could be considered an example. Consider, from Wikipedia:

> Originally it was established outside the city walls of Dublin in the
>   buildings of the dissolved Augustinian Priory of All Hallows. Trinity
>   College was set up in part to consolidate the rule of the Tudor
>   monarchy in Ireland, and it was seen as the university of the
>   Protestant Ascendancy for much of its history. Although Catholics and
>   Dissenters had been permitted to enter as early as 1793, certain
>   restrictions on their membership of the college remained until 1873
>   (professorships, fellowships and scholarships were reserved for
>   Protestants). From 1871 to 1970, the Catholic Church in Ireland
>   forbade its adherents from attending Trinity College without
>   permission. Women were first admitted to the college as full members
>   in January 1904.